# How to convert iptables command line to Ufw Command line?

Tags: command-line, iptables, firewall, ufw

I'm new to Ubuntu, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on my server.

I have a questions that maybe some Master Ubuntu Expert in this forum could kindly help me out.

- Is IPtables command line are different with Ufw command line ?
- If so, how could I translate bellow command line into Ufw command line ? (I couldn't have GUI Ufw since I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 server version without GUI).

//VPS\

```
sudo iptables -P FORWARD DROP
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

//VPS-port 80

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -p tcp --syn --dport 80 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.2 
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -p tcp --dport 80 -d 192.168.4.2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.4.1
```

//VPS-port 443

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wg0 -p tcp --syn --dport 443 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.2     
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -p tcp --dport 443 -d 192.168.4.2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.4.1
```

//HomeServer\

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.2    
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.2    
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -p tcp --dport 80 -d 192.168.4.2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.4.1   
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg0 -p tcp --dport 443 -d 192.168.4.2 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.4.1
```

Comment: Where did you come up with those iptables commands? If you're sure that's exactly what you need, you can just use `iptables` without bothering with ufw.

Answer (score 1):

> Is IPtables command line are different with Ufw command line ?

Yes definitely, see `man iptables` and `man ufw`

> how could i translate bellow command line into Ufw command line ?

You can't since ufw doesn't have all the functionalities you need for your case. However, ufw is using iptables under the hood. So you can add iptables rules to ufw. See for example : [IP masquerading - Ubuntu server guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20190601191448/https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html.en#ip-masquerading)

Comment: Sadly link is broken. Still interest into executing `iptables` comands under Ubuntu when ufw is used.

Comment: `the current back-end for ufw is iptables-restore with the rules files located in /etc/ufw/*.rules. `  So I can use the dump from iptable-save, which is exactly what I need.  But the word "currently" makes me worry... might this break in the future?